# ReportViewer (remote mode) in VS 2008 and ReportingService Server 2008 not possible?

Tags: reportviewer

MSDN says about Report Viewer in VS 2008:
"The ReportViewer controls require information that is only exposed through the SQL Server 2005 SOAP execution endpoint."

http://www.gotreportviewer.com/ says about Report Viewer in VS 2008:
"In remote mode the ReportViewer control can only view reports hosted on a SQL Server 2005 Report Server".

Is there really no Update unitl now for using ReportViewer in VS 2008 in remote mode together with Reporting Service Server 2008 ?

I'm getting error message when using it:
"# The version of the report server web service definition (WSDL) is either not valid or unrecognized. The server is not a compatible version.
 * System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header 'SOAPAction': 
 ...schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices/LoadReport..."

Comment: It seems like it is still not supported. http://blogs.msdn.com/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/19/better-report-viewing-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx --  Try to install Visual Studio 2010 and use the ReportViewer control from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's quite correct (I'm up and running using ReportViewer in VS2008 against a report server under SQL Server 2008).

Here's my interpretation of the 'rules':

1) A ReportViewer in CLIENT processing mode can't display reports created in VS2008 (Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008) because it doesn't have the necessary code to handle new report objects that were introduced since SQL Server 2005.

2) A ReportViewer in REMOTE processing mode can display reports from SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services because the server itself handles the report building. ReportViewer just streams the results back from the report server.

3) The "SQL Server 2005 SOAP execution endpoint" is what you're actually hitting with ReportViewer, I believe (can anyone confirm this?). I just finished wrapping the SOAP API for my web app that handles publishing reports and the WSDL is called ReportingServer2005.asmx (there's also a ReportingService2006.asmx to be used for SharePoint integration) - there's no 2008.

I'm just moving us from SQL Server 2000 to 2008, so all of my reports aren't using any newer features like the tablix. It's certainly possible that ReportViewer can't display a report from 2008 if it uses any new visual components that were introduced in 2008.